# callback function doesn't print, unless ran by Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Here is the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem.

I call an API with a callback function that prints what comes out of the API call.

If I run this code in Jupyter, I get the output. If I run it with `python file.py` I don't get any output. I already checked the API's code, but that does nothing weird. Setting `DEBUGGING` to `True` isn't helpful either.

Note that there is once dependency; the Bitvavo API. Install it with `pip install python-bitvavo-api`

```
# %%
from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo

# %%
def generic_callback(response):
    print(f"log function=get_markets, {response=}")

bitvavo = Bitvavo({"DEBUGGING": False})
websocket = bitvavo.newWebsocket()

# %%
websocket.markets(options={"market": "BTC-EUR"}, callback=generic_callback)
```

Here is the expected output I get from Jupyter:

```
log function:get_markets, response={'market': 'BTC-EUR', 'status': 'trading', 'base': 'BTC', 'quote': 'EUR', 'pricePrecision': 5, 'minOrderInBaseAsset': '0.0001', 'minOrderInQuoteAsset': '5', 'orderTypes': ['market', 'limit', 'stopLoss', 'stopLossLimit', 'takeProfit', 'takeProfitLimit']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a websocket, the callback is executed by a different thread, which means that if you don't wait, the main thread (which is to receive the `print`'s output) will already be killed.

Add a `sleep(1)` (that's seconds, not ms) at the end and the output will show.

PS: The reason Jupyter *does* show the output, is because Jupyter keeps an interactive window open the entire time, even far after you've run the code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo

# %%
def generic_callback(response):
    print(f"log function=get_markets, {response=}")

bitvavo = Bitvavo({"DEBUGGING": False})
websocket = bitvavo.newWebsocket()

# Wait N.1 required to receive output, otherwise the main thread is killed
time.sleep(1)

# %%
websocket.markets(options={"market": "BTC-EUR"}, callback=generic_callback)

# Wait N.2 required to receive output, otherwise the main thread is killed
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @NostraDavid If my answer, or that of other users, was the solution to your question, please accept the answer as Stackoverflow Help Center rules, thank you